# How to pass values between lightbox?

Tags: jquery, html

I am using [lightbox jquery](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/).

**HTML**

```
<div id="light" class="white_content">
            <img id="closelightbox" src="Images/ExitButton.png" />
            <div id="player"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="fade" class="black_overlay">
        </div>
```

I am using following thing to load page

```
 $("#fade").show();
 $("#player").load("../Html/mypagename.html");
}
$("#light").show();
```

**I have 2 pages : 1 Customer , 2 Product**

How can I pass some value from the customer page to product page?

- Usercome to customer page, -
  -Customer Details With Product grid will be showed then

  - Clicking on something will Load Product Page, do something at Product page, again back to customer page and previously showed details on customer should be visible at that time.

Comment: As they're being loaded into the same page with ajax, just prefix all the variables with `window.` and you'll be able to reference them throughout.

Answer (score -1):

HTML is stateless in general. Meaning, you cannot pass values across different pages unless you maintain a *session* or a *cookie*.

To set a cookie using javascript, you can follow this tutorial:

http://www.thonky.com/javascript-and-css-guide/set-cookie/

If you prefer using jQuery to set the cookie, you may do so doing this:

[How do I set/unset cookie with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-to-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery)

To use sessions to pass around data is a little more complicated. This would require some knowledge on how to work with server side programming like Java, PHP, RoR, etc.

Comment: He's not changing pages - he's using ajax to load new pages.

Comment: The question was not clear and it was later updated. Thanks for the down vote.

Comment: How was the question not clear when his code included `$("#player").load("../Html/mypagename.html");`?  Seems perfectly clear to me.  The down vote wasn't because what you said was wrong - it just wasn't relevant.